# Consistent height for form elements (input) across browsers and devices

Tags: html, flexbox

Please refer the following code snippet

```html
<input type="button" style="line-height:20px" value="button 20">
<input type="text" style="line-height:20px" value="text 20">
```

Actual height obtained is 24.8px as seen using browser developer tools

[image]

This is not a problem if behavior was consistent across browsers and mobile devices. Even when `appearance:none` is applied, I don't get consistent height across devices. For example, iPhones gives different height for button and text-field and UI looks bad.

Can anyone help me to understand how actual height is calculated for these form elements and what is the best way to get a consistent behavior across browsers and devices.

Comment: Padding could have something to do with it.

Comment: i tried resetting padding. but no consistency for this

Comment: What are you intend to do?

Comment: The height of  an element consists of multiple dimensions. Either it is up to its parent, to its own height setting, to the border defined, the padding defined, the margin defined etc. etc. so we really need more insights on what you would like to achieve/tried

Comment: note that, setting a height amd line-height for buttons seem to work everywhere. But text field is still ignoring height

Comment: @SMAKSS, i just want to know how the height is calculated so that I can find a fix to get uniform height for form elements in all browsers and mobile devices

Comment: @Joans, can u please give inputs, assuming these elements are inside a div without any styles applied.

Comment: as of now, i am getting a consistent behavior when setting padding to 0 and applying line-height and height. but still not getting how exactly height is calculated by different devices/browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to know [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) will indicate each line box height, so in different OSs with different type font and settings it may result and act differently, to indicate a height of elements such as `input` you need to use [`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height) property instead of `line-height`.

But if you use `height` you will face the same issue as before, it seems weird in the first place but **this is all about [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)**. The **`<input type="text" />` has `box-sizing: content-box;` by default and the `<input type="button" />`** *(Also, `<button>` itself)* **has `box-sizing: border-box;`**.

> - `content-box` gives you the default CSS box-sizing behavior. If you set an element's width to 100 pixels, then the element's content box will be 100 pixels wide, and the width of any border or padding will be added to the final rendered width, making the element wider than 100px.
> - `border-box` tells the browser to account for any border and padding in the values you specify for an element's width and height. If you set an element's width to 100 pixels, that 100 pixels will include any border or padding you added, and the content box will shrink to absorb that extra width. This typically makes it much easier to size elements.

So we just have to change the default `box-sizing` of `<input type="button" />` to `content-box`. Then the result will be what you looking for.

```css
input {
  height: 20px;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="button 20">
<input type="text" value="text 20">
```

### UPDATE

For those who encounter an odd behavior in firefox about showing these elements, I have to say it is about the differentiation between these two elements `padding` and `border`. The `height` of these two are even but the amount of top and bottom `border` for `button` is `3px` each and the padding for it is `0` whilst the input got `border` of `1px` and padding of `2px` for each top and bottom `border`. So it will cause the odd look of these elements in firefox.

To fix this you have to make sure the padding and border for these elements are in an equal amount just like this:

```css
input {
  height: 20px;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="button 20">
<input type="text" value="text 20">
```

Comment: your answer is very useful, things are getting clear. However, note that even this code cannot be consistent. checking in firefox 78.0.1 in windows and result is not as expected

Comment: @Kiran Well, it is not about `box-sizing` stuff, this is because Mozilla is a bit buggy about differentiating `border` and `padding`. Since the `button` got `3px` border by default, no padding and input got `2px` padding with `1px` border it will seem a mess in firefox. So to fix this you have to make sure both elements have same amount of `border` and `padding`.